# 2 раздельно открываемый ul

Tags: javascript, html

"Открыть подменю" 2 и их открывать поочередно, при открытие первого закрыть второе, при закрытие второго- открывать первый

```
 <script>
 function toggle(el)
 {
 el.style.display = (el.style.display == 'none') ? 'block' : 'none';
 }
 </script>



<a onclick="toggle(document.getElementById('sub-menu'))">Открыть подменю</a> 
<div id="dd" style="display:none">+</div>
<ul id="sub-menu" style="display:none">
<li><a href="#1">подпункт 1</a></li>
<li><a href="#2">подпункт 2</a></li>
<li><a href="#3">подпункт 3</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: То что вы пытаетесь сделать называется "Аккордеон" в интернете множество примеров реализации.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот небольшой пример:

```css
.cd-accordion-menu input[type=checkbox] {
 position: absolute;
 opacity: 0;
}
.cd-accordion-menu label, .cd-accordion-menu a {
 position: relative;
 display: block;
 padding: 18px 18px 18px 64px;
 background: #4d5158;
 box-shadow: inset 0 -1px #555960;
 color: #ffffff;
 font-size: 1.6rem;
}

.cd-accordion-menu ul {
 display: none;
}

.cd-accordion-menu input[type=checkbox]:checked + label + ul,
.cd-accordion-menu input[type=checkbox]:checked + label:nth-of-type(n) + ul {
 display: block;
}
```

```html
<ul class="cd-accordion-menu">
 <li class="has-children">
  <input type="checkbox" name ="group-1" id="group-1" checked>
  <label for="group-1">Group 1</label>
    <ul>
     <li class="has-children">
      <input type="checkbox" name ="sub-group-1" id="sub-group-1">
    <label for="sub-group-1">Sub Group 1</label>

    <ul>
     <li><a href="#0">Image</a></li>
     <li><a href="#0">Image</a></li>
     <li><a href="#0">Image</a></li>
    </ul>
     </li>
     <li><a href="#0">Image</a></li>
   <li><a href="#0">Image</a></li>
    </ul>
 </li>

 <li><a href="#0">Image</a></li>
 <li><a href="#0">Image</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: не совсем то, ну ладно...Спасибо большое!